# Make view behind present ViewController visible

Tags: iphone, ios, modal-dialog, transition, uigraphicscontext

I'd like to be able to dismiss my modals by sliding them down. To do, I'd like to be able to see the previous view controller behind the current one as I drag it down.

To do so, I encapsulated my view in a scroll view and I tried to print an image of the previous VC behind so as I slide down I can see it. Unfortunately it does work, all I can see is a black screen.

I used this code to do this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

[self.navigationController.viewControllers[ self.navigationController.viewControllers.count-1].view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:viewImage];
```

Does anyone has an idea on how to do this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you can add the "above" view controller this way:

```
[self.scrollview addsubview:secondVC.view];
```

and sure u have to decrease the opacity of the view to see through